# InfluxDB: storing audio or video

Tags: database, audio, video, sensors, influxdb

We are looking at InfluxDB to store large numbers of streamed measurements (1-2 tera-samples).  Additionally, we would like to be able to also store audio and video streams corresponding to the measurements (not all of them but many).  To me at least this makes sense, since it is all time base data.  But I don't see any discussion of this online.
I imagine that the video data could be broken up into frames.  And that the audio data could be broken up into 100msec audio frames.
Has anyone tried this?  Any recommendations?

Comment: To be honest, I don't think that InfluxDb would be good for storing audio/video streams. Wouldn't it be better to store that in some kind of storage (depending on what you're using - private server, cloud service..). InfluxDb is specialized for "metric-y" kind of data, and audio/video streams are not that. It probably wouldn't be worth it. You can always use InfluxDb in conjunction with other types of DB's and/or storage.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I understand your point.  Perhaps we are using the database a little differently that most.  We are looking to record ongoing streams of measured data (around 100Hz sampling rate) for long periods.  Each measurement is small (a byte or two) and there will be many simultaneous streams.   (continued)

Comment: (continued) The primary goal is to be able to pull out individual measurements (across all streams) that are aligned in time (say, all measurements across all streams at 11:00:00am).  Some of the streams are audio and others are video, and we will need to pull out the individual audio/video frames at that same time (say, 11:00:00am).  So we need time synchronized access across many streams.  My thoughts are that a time-series database would be good for this.

Comment: (continued) Certainly we could store the video in separate database with a link and timecode to point to the individual frame.  But it just seems inefficient.  Each stream measurement will be one byte (reported every 10msec) and will need to contain maybe 100 bytes of linking & timecode information to point to the parallel database.  With 100 samples per second multiplied by 30 measurements each with 100 bytes of linking data, that's 300KB of wasted information.  Sigh.  Anyway, that is the problem as I see it.  Thanks.

Comment: How did you make out on this? I was about to start a project this weekend that sounds similar - though I was debating between Elastic and InfluxDB.

Comment: Honestly, I'm still surprised that there is no proposed answer for this.  Storing large numbers of data items in time would seem to be a valuable use case.  We ultimately chose to store our data in 30 minute chunks in protobuf files in AWS S3.  We then need to scan through the data to acquire the subsets we need.  Very inefficient, but at least it's manageable.  Also media links can be stored once in the BP file with time-value ranges to the cover the data items.

Answer (score 2):

Most time-series databases are optimized for storing floating point values, with the occasional string here and there. Storing BLOBs beyond perhaps 1KB is likely not a good use case for InfluxDB, although we haven't done much performance testing with larger binary data.

That said, I don't quite follow your use case. It seems more like you need to index audio and video, rather than store and analyze time series data. TSDBs aren't just optimized for storing things with time as the primary axis, they are also optimized for aggregating those values and looking for change over time. Your use case doesn't seem to involve any aggregation or pattern searching, just a simple look-up table by time.

I would think a NoSQL database would be just as good for this, or perhaps OpenTSDB, which builds on top of Cassandra.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Our need is to aggregate 20-30 streams of time-based sensor data (100-200Hz) and to get all measurements that are time aligned at say, 10:00:00am on a given date.  And since the data is all asynchronous (with its own timebase) we need to get the samples that are closest in time to each other at that time point.  So, would this still be the right choice for a TSDB?  Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a more reasonable use case for a TSDB. You can store the timebase as a field and the actual calendar time as the timestamp, and then query points that lie on the same timestamp or within a range of timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ReductStore](https://github.com/reductstore). It is an open source database for this exact use case. It has the capability to store blob data within a time-series database.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34635711)